# Number of paths in a board with a puncture

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A picture of the board and my solution

[image: punctured_board]

I have this $8 \times 6$ board but there is a restriction with it - we have a hole with a bottom-left corner at $(3, 2)$ and top-right at $(6, 4)$. I need to count the number of possible ways to get from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner of the board.

Since there are two ways to go around the hole, I counted them and summed them. Is my solution correct or did I miss something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what moves are allowed ?

Comment: Only down and right - so only y-1 and x+1

Comment: Put the number $1$ in the top left corner & use the usual Pascal triangle recurrence relation, with the obvious restriction at the hole.

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick here is to mark diagonal lines of cells such that all paths pass through exactly one of those cells.

```
S.......1
.......2.
......3..
....  ...
...4.....
..5......
.6......E
```

Now the result is a sum of products of binomials:

- $\binom80\binom60=1$ path goes through cell 1.
- $\binom81\binom61=48$ paths go through cell 2.
- $\binom82\binom62=420$ paths go through cell 3.
- $\binom73\binom72=735$ paths go through cell 4.
- $\binom72\binom71=147$ paths go through cell 5.
- $\binom71\binom70=7$ paths go through cell 6.

Thus there are 1358 paths in total.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is a variant which evaluates  the number of valid lattice paths by iteratively adding up the number of valid paths with  shorter length.
>
> [image]
>
> We conclude  in concordance with the  answer of @ParclyTaxel:
> The number of valid paths is $$\color{blue}{1358}$$

Comment: In particular, Markus is finding the number of valid paths at each vertex except the upper left by adding the numbers at the vertices directly above and directly to the left of the vertex.

Answer (score 1):

If the board did not contain a hole, any path would involve eight moves to the right and six downward moves.  The path is completely determined by choosing which six of the fourteen moves are downward.  Hence, without the hole, there would be $$\binom{14}{6}$$ possible paths.

From these, we must exclude those paths that pass through the two missing vertices.  With your labeling system, these vertices are at $(4, 3)$ and $(5, 3)$.

Paths that would pass through the vertex $(4, 3)$:  The vertex $(4, 3)$ is four units to the right and three units down from the top left corner, so there would be $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to reach the vertex from the left corner.  The vertex $(4, 3)$ is also four units to the left and three units up from the bottom right corner, so there would be $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to reach the bottom right corner from $(4, 3)$.  Hence, the number of paths that would pass through the vertex $(4, 3)$ would be 
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{7}{3}$$

Paths that would pass through the vertex $(5, 3)$:  The vertex $(5, 3)$ is five units to the right and three units from the top left corner, so there would be $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to reach the vertex from the top left corner.  The vertex $(5, 3)$ is three units to the left and three units up from the bottom right corner, so there would be $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to reach the bottom right corner from $(5, 3)$.  Hence, the number of paths that would pass through the vertex $(5, 3)$ would be 
$$\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}$$

However, if we simply subtract the number of paths that pass through these vertices from the total, we will have subtracted paths that pass through both of these vertices twice.  We only want to subtract those paths once, so we must add them back.

Paths that would pass through both the vertices $(4, 3)$ and $(5, 3)$:  There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to reach $(4, 3)$ from the upper left corner, one way to reach $(5, 3)$ from $(4, 3)$, and $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to reach the bottom right corner from $(5, 3)$.

Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of permissible paths is 
$$\binom{14}{6}  - \binom{7}{3}\binom{7}{3} - \binom{8}{3}\binom{6}{3} + \binom{7}{3}\binom{6}{3}$$

Comment: Actually, the question is ambiguous on this regard. It is not specified whether the line intersections or the squares they define are of interest. These lead to the two different answers we got.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  The OP refers to a missing rectangle with bottom left vertex $(3, 2)$ and top right vertex $(6, 4)$, so it seems reasonable to assume that the paths are along the grid lines and that the corners refer to the vertices.

Comment: Finished "expanding" my answer to account for this.

Comment: To clarify the issue, indeed, the paths are along the grid lines. I apologize for the ambiguity. Thank you for the thorough explanations on the answers!